issues on converting an Enum to a object and use the == operator
In my opinion, this C# program should output "True", but actually it outputs "False", how to explain?
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  object obj = System.IO.FileMode.Create;
  Console.WriteLine(obj == (object)System.IO.FileMode.Create);
}


If you did show us your real use-case, we could possibly show you a working alternative.

In short - because of boxing.

Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type. When the common language runtime (CLR) boxes a value type, it wraps the value inside a System.Object instance and stores it on the managed heap

After boxing you have the object. You have two casts to the object (two boxing operations), so you have two different independent objects. And when objects are compared, they are compared by the reference, not by the value. And independent objects obviously, have different places in memory, so the comparison gives false.

System.IO.FileMode.Create as an enum, it's stored as a simple value. But when you cast it to object, it gets boxed (wrapped) into an object. Since you're creating two separate boxed objects, comparing them checks if they are the same object in memory, not if they have the same value.
